# Create union literal type from key values

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

The `TableData` type has the same properties as the return type of the following function

```
const createTableData = (cod: string, promo: string, type: string) => ({
  __typename: "TableData",
  code: cod,
  promo: promo,
  type: type
})

type TableData = ReturnType<typeof createTableData>
```

I need to create a store dict which keys should be the same values as the `code` key of `TableData`. In other words I'm trying to create a type of the union literals of `TableData["code"]` without success, for example

```
type SampleCode = "1234" | "1235" | "7631" | "4012"
type CodeTableData = SampleCode

class TableDataMock {
  private store: Record<CodeTableData, TableData | undefined> = {
    1234: undefined,
    1235: undefined,
    7631: undefined,
    4012: undefined
  }
}
```

As you can see the `store` keys will be the future values of the `TableData["code"]` but in my example the `SampleCode` type has already been initialized with prior values.

EDIT:

The end result should look like this

```
const createTableData = (cod: string, promo: string, type: string) => ({
  __typename: "TableData",
  code: "123",
  promo: promo,
  type: type
})

type TableDataStore = {[C in ReturnType<typeof createTableData>["code"]]: undefined}

class TableDataMock {
  private store: TableDataStore = {"123": undefined, "234": undefined}
                                                      ^^^^
                                                     this should not be valid
}
```

The only valid keys of `TableDataStore` should be `123`. Besides this example I need that the keys of `TableDataStore` should be the future values of the `code` property of `TableData`.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. How should `SampleCode` look like instead?

Comment: `SampleCode` should be the end result. I need to create a type from the values of the `code` key of `TableData`. Hope that is clear now.

Comment: but `code` seems to accept any `string` value. Is it known at compile time which values are possible for `code`?

Comment: @TobiasS. please check the edit thank you

Comment: does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAVZAjANogIqsjALwwAUoAJgFwzTwCWYA5gDQwAO8IAtiHQbN2MKAE9OiQVCasAlKQB8FAN4AoGDAD6W8ZLDJeUmACJMuAkRNsNcEFWMmAjACYAzNdvc+Arj342mnrGwWoAvjDIEHaQUAoA9PEwADwAtJHRoLEwABaISGpqwTDmeIRQyADKUCBIpDAqANoAwjDMMABKiFAArvBg6BKIycEgAGZwSKgY2GVEio0m1IgmALqrdD1gDmPMiFRhhcA4UdGllhUAsiDAANYNXkwAbtP0NUh05+VV74j1Ks53CZNttELswPsOCZ3AAWYEwLY7PYHcJAA) work for you?

Comment: Yes, do you mind me asking for an explanation?

Comment: It has to do with "type widening". You can see an example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAQzgXjgb0QLjgIgQIxBzgF9gB6cuauAPQH5hRJY58V0tcCjTEo44aDApUaDJsBgBPAA4BTODIVgAZgEEOy+WsQBtPDgC6omnUZS5i7WoBCWq7vwGEx0+PpA). Typescript will often widen literal types like `"abc"` to `string`. But you can narrow down the type with `as const`